# Designing Sharepoint 2013 in designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to edit may share point 2013 site in designer 2010 (because of design view window)
how can I open my share point 2013 site in designer 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is an interesting though, but no, you cannot open sharepoint sites with different versions of the designer

Comment: Hi dear Tiago and thank you for your helping I want to change the presentation of items in my web parts (custom list) and I know I should customize items.xslt file but I am not expert with xsl and xml what should I do??

Comment: honestly, you should learn xslt. my advise is to pick a basic starting point go get you going and if you have trouble, ask a question on a specific problem you are having. in sp2013 you also have display templates so you can take a look at that

Comment: Thank you and do you know any practical resource for learning xslt for sp2013?

Comment: xslt is basically a file with some html and data that you can customize. I dont know any specific sharepoint resource for learning xslt but I think if you learn xslt in general you will be good to do. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Your mean first of all I should learn xsl language then go to style library and copy items.xslt and then modify that?

Comment: yes, something like that. depends a bit on what you are trying to to. again, try to understand xslt, try to actually achieve something and if you have trouble, then ask a question on that

Comment: dont forget to accept answers for your questions so others know your problem is solved. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work